# manipulating Microsoft Word DOCX files that have links and track changes using Python

Tags: ms-word, python-docx

I have been using the excellent [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to read, modify, and write Microsoft Word files. The package supports extracting the text from each paragraph. It also allows accessing a paragraph a "run" at a time, where the run is a set of characters that have the same font information. Unfortunately, when you access a paragraph by runs, you lose the links, because the package does not support links. The package also does not support accessing change tracking information.

My problem is that I need to access change tracking information. Or, more specifically, I need to copy paragraphs that have change tracking indicated from one document to another.

I've tried doing this at the XML level. For example, this code snippet appends the contents of file1.docx to file2.docx:

```
from docx import Document
doc1 = Document("file1.docx")
doc2 = Document("file2.docx")
doc2.element.body.append(doc1.element.body)
doc2.save("file2-appended.docx")
```

When I try to open the file on my Mac for complicated files, I get this error:

[image]

But if I click OK, the contents are there. The manipulation also works without problem for very simple files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.element` attribute is really an "internal" interface and should be named `._element`. In most other places I have named it that. What you're getting there is the root element of the document part. You can see what it is by calling:

```
print(doc2.element.xml)
```

That element has one and only one `w:body` element below it, which is what you get when with `doc2.element.body` (`.xml` will work on that too, btw, if you want to inspect that element).

What your code is doing is appending one body element at the end of another `w:body` element and thereby forming invalid XML. The WordprocessingML vocabulary is quite strict about what element can follow another and how many and so forth. The only surprise for me is that it actually sometimes works for you, I take it :)

If you want to manipulate the XML directly, which is what the `._element` attribute is there for, you need to do it carefully, in view of the (complex) WordprocessingML XML Schema.

Unlike when you stick to the published API, there's no safety net once `._element` (or `.element`) appears in your code.

Inside the body XML can be relationships to external document parts, like images and hyperlinks. These will only be valid within the document in which they appear. This might explain why some files can be repaired.

Comment: Hm. This is good news, but it's frustrating for me.  I have the immediate need to one thing—namely, merge paragraphs from multiple files while retaining change-tracking. Instead of appending the doc2.element.body to another doc.element.body, would it make more sense to take all of the children from doc2's doc2.element.body  and append them, child-by-child, to doc.element.body?

Comment: I suppose it's worth a try. There are definitely ways that can break a document, but depending on your content it might work. Probably the most likely things to screw it up are images and hyperlinks. Both of those reference external items that would have to be brought over separately. Note that you can't just append your new items to the end of the `w:body` element, that "last-child" location is reserved for a `w:sectPr` element. So you'll have to insert them before `body[-1]`. The docs have more here: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/sections.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't realize about the last-child location. I guess I better not copy that over...

Comment: Argh! comments are stored in comments.xml! I really need to merge comments and change tracking as well.

Comment: @vy32 You have a challenging project on your hands :)